# Updating enterprise iOS apps while retaining some files of the current app bundle

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, enterprise, ipod

Currently, to deploy our enterprise app, we get the client to download the latest app build bundle and install it using the iPhone Configuration Utility. Unfortunately when they uninstall the current build of the app, it removes all its related files on the device. They need to uninstall the app before being able to install the new build of the app.

Is there a way to update to the new build while retaining some of the existing files on the device so that the entire app isn't completely reset (e.g. logging and setting files)?

There doesn't seem to be an update enterprise app mechanism unlike the regular app store, or have I missed a feature somewhere?

Comment: I would have expected that updating the CFBundleVersion and/or the  CFBundleShortVersionString should tell the iCU to update instead of replace. iTunes is doing it this way. Once you have an "update" then only the app bundle is replaced, the documents directory will stay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to update OTA (over the air); this will replace the app "in place" as long as the bundle id is the same (suggest you use a new version number). You can deploy this yourself using an XML file per the Wireless App spec, or use a solution such as EASE (Enterprise App Services Environment) [http://www.apperian.com/ease]. In either case, the apps will be replaced on the springboard as soon as the app successfully installs.